# antlr4 mismatch input error on sql parser

Tags: antlr4

I am getting following error on parsing but not sure why it's happening.

line 1:24 mismatched input '1' expecting NUM
line 1:24 mismatched input '1' expecting NUM
select a from abc limit 1 ;

--

grammar SQLCmd;

parse : sql
;

sql : ('select' ((columns (',' columns)*)|count) 'from')
      tables
      ('where' condition ((and|or) condition)*)*  (limit)? ';'
;

limit : 'limit' NUM
;

num : NUM
;

count : 'count(*)'
;

columns : VAL
;

tables : VAL
;

condition : ( left '=' right )+
;

and : 'and'
;

or : 'or'
;

left : VAL
;

right : VAL
;

VAL : [*a-z0-9A-Z~?]+
;

NUM : [0-9]+
;

WS : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip
;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a `VAL` instead of a `NUM`.

The "1" is both a `VAL` and a `NUM` but since `VAL` comes first, there will *never* be `NUM` tokens since every `NUM` will be a `VAL`.

Try putting the `NUM` rule before the `VAL` rule.

You could have found out this by yourself by looking at the token types from the lexer. This will tell you the actual type of the token that is present.

@TheAntlrGuy: Maybe one could add the actual token type to the error message?

Comment: Thanks! Why would VAL be matched first when it explicitly says 'limit' NUM in the parser rule?

Comment: Because _all_ lexing is done before the parser is involved. This has to do with lookahead which should not depend on the context (see "context free grammar").